# Variance of Log Returns

Tags: variance, log-returns, auto-correlation

Consider an asset held for $n$ time periods with weakly stationary log-returns $r_t$, $1≤t≤n$.

Show that
$var(r_1 +r_2 +r_3 +r_4)=var(r_1 +r_2 +r_3)+var(r_1)(1+2ρ_3 +2ρ_2 +2ρ_1)$,
where $ρ_k$ is the autocorrelation of ${r_t}$ at lag $k$.

I assume there is something simple I am missing, I have got to..

$var(r_1+r_2+r_3+r_4)= var(r_1) + var(r_2) + var(r_3) + var(r_4)$

$ = var(r_1+r_2+r_3) + var(r_4)$

==> $var(r_4) = var(r_1)(1+2ρ_3+2ρ_2+2ρ_1) $

But I'm struggling to prove the final result, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can't write $var(r_1+r_2+r_3+r_4)= var(r_1) + var(r_2) + var(r_3) + var(r_4)$, since the autocorrelations are non-zero.

Comment: ok back to the drawing board, thank you.

Comment: Maybe start with just two returns $r_1,r_2$ which are autocorrelated and then try to expand to 3 and 4.

Comment: Maybe compute $\Sigma$, the 4x4 covariance matrix of the four returns (it will be a 'Toeplitz matrix'), then compute $\vec{1}^{\top}\Sigma \vec{1}$.

Comment: isn't this just a horrible econometric substitution, given var(a+b) = var(a) + var(b) + 2 * rho(a,b) * sigma(a) * sigma(b)